# Why {a: '1'}.toString() fails and var obj= {a: '1'}; obj.toString() does not

Tags: javascript, object

I was wondering whether execution of these two has any difference to the JS interpreter.
is this because we can not create and call method on object simultaneously.?
Any help on this?

Comment: I'm sure this has been answered somewhere... Just gotta find it

Comment: try this: `({}).toString()` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because JavaScript will interpret your curly brace as a block, not an object. Try with:

```
({}).toString()
```

Comment: _"JavaScript code can't start with a curly brace."_ isn't true. `{}+[]` is a valid JavaScript statement.

Comment: "JavaScript code can't start with a curly brace" — It can. It just isn't an object, so you can't call methods on it.

Comment: Sorry, I've updated

Comment: And now this answer is correct, but inferior to those in the dupe target.